# C++ templated class and init in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename, class-constructors

I have a templated class, Foo :

```
template <class A, class B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(A &aInstance);

private:
    Attr<Foo> _attr;
};
```

Then I have another templated class called Attr which is an attribute of my Foo class and which takes as template parameter the Foo class itself.

```
template <class C>
class Attr
{
    class SomeType
    {
        SomeType();
        ~SomeType();
    };

    Attr(const SomeType* st);
    ~Attr();

private:
    Attr();
}
```

I want to init _attr (of type Attr) in the constructor, casting the first parameter from the template as SomeType.

Foo constructor implementation :

```
template<class A, class B>
Foo<A, B>::Foo(A &aInstance):
    _attr(
        (Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) aInstance)
{

}
```

This won't compile :

error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

That error refers to the cast line in the Foo contructor implementation, as if SomeType was not recognized.

I now have an instance, but still got the same error.

Comment: I’ve rolled back your last edit since that has rendered the question (and its answers) nonsensical. Please don’t do that. As for the other edits: these *also* interfere with the existing answers; I haven’t rolled them back but please in the future *add* further clarification, don’t change the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 0)

```
(Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) A)
```

at that point, `A` is a typename, i.e. the name of a type, thus, not anything you can cast.

## 1)

Also, `Foo<A,B>` is dependent upon `A` and `B`, therefore, `Attr<Foo<A, B> >` is a dependent name, too. Hence, you need a `typename` there so as to tell the compiler that `SomeType` is a type:

```
(typename Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) somePointer)
```

## 2)

Furthermore, in C++, generally prefer C++-casts over C-style-casts. You'll catch a lot of mistakes with them. See also [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) :)

## 3)

On the other hand: Are you sure you need the cast by design, or should `Attr` point to exactly a `Foo<A, B>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class A, class B>
Foo<A, B>::Foo():
    _attr(
        (Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) A)
{

}
```

`A` is a type, and you're trying to pass it to constructor. You need an instance here.

Comment: I believe `typename` is also necessary here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Attr class does not (in your snippet) use the C type, so you should explain where it is used, and what is the relation between C and SomeType.

Second, in this lines

```
Foo<A, B>::Foo():
    _attr(
        (Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) A)
```

A is a type and not an object. If _attr should be initialized with the Foo object itself, then you should pass pointer this.

```
Foo<A, B>::Foo():
    _attr(
        (Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) this)
```

However, that this point, the Foo object is not yet constructed, so beware what you do with the pointer in the Attr constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your constructor to:

```
template<class A, class B>
Foo<A, B>::Foo(A &aInstance):
    _attr(
        (typename Attr<Foo<A, B> >::SomeType *) &aInstance) {}
```

You will, because you want a pointer, need to add an address-of operator in order to take the address of the instance object ... otherwise `aInstance` will not a pointer-type, instead it will be reference type which is effectively the same as passing the object itself (by reference), rather than a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. A couple of typedefs help in making sense of templated code a little easier:

```
template<class C>
class Attr
{
public:
    class SomeType
    {
        SomeType();
       ~SomeType();
    };

    typedef typename Attr<C>::SomeType ReachIntoSomeType;

    Attr(const SomeType* st) { }
    ~Attr() { }

private:
    Attr();
};

template <class A, class B>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(A &aInstance) : _attr(reinterpret_cast<AttrOfFoo::ReachIntoSomeType*>(aInstance))     
    { }

private:
    typedef Attr<Foo> AttrOfFoo;
    AttrOfFoo _attr;
};
```

Comment: Good God! The code is completely screwed up! First time in SO. Can someone correct it for me? Thanks!